# How to improve my turn based game loop code

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops

I embarked on a journey to create a turn-based fighting game. I just wanted to get your feedback on of the code. I am at a bit of a problem as I am trying to figure out how I can go about not repeating the following lines of code...

```
move_command = input("What move would you like to use? one, two, three, or four? ")


  if move_command == "one":
      for key in player.move_one:
          print("You used {}".format(key))
          print("")
      bot_damage = player.move_one[key][0]
      mana_used = player.move_one[key][1]


  if move_command == "two":
      for key in player.move_two:
          print("You used {}".format(key))
          print("")
      bot_damage = player.move_two[key][0]
      mana_used = player.move_two[key][1]

  if move_command == "three":
      for key in player.move_three:
          print("You used {}".format(key))
          print("")
      bot_damage = player.move_three[key][0]
      mana_used = player.move_three[key][1]



  if move_command == "four":
      for key in player.move_four:
          print("You used {}".format(key))
          print("")
      bot_damage = player.move_four[key][0]
      mana_used = player.move_four[key][1]
```

I believe I can make a function that will help me cut these 4 blocks down two one, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I know that I have to be flexible with my player.move_"one" attribute and my move_command, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the options into a dictionary and assign each option as a key and the result to its value. From there, you can simply pass in the key to a function that will use the associated value.

```
move_command = input("What move would you like to use? one, two, three, or four? ")

move_dict = {"one": player.move_one, "two": player.move_two, "three": player.move_three, "four": player.move_four}

do_command(move_command)
```

Where `do_command()` is defined as:

```
def do_command(command_number):
    for key in move_dict[command_number]:
        print("You used {}".format(key))
        print("")
      bot_damage = player.move_one[key][0]
      mana_used = player.move_one[key][1]
```